# Proof in complex function - Is the function bounded?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function which is not constant.
$g: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is defined as
$$ g(z) =\begin{cases}
1, & f(z)=0  \\[2ex]
\dfrac{|f(z)|+1}{|f(z)|} \cdot f(z) ,& f(z) \neq 0
\end{cases}
$$

And  $h:  B_1(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ is defined as $ h(z)=  \displaystyle\int_{C_{1,0}}^{} g(z-w) \,dz$.

Is the function $h$ bounded function in $B_1(0)$?

I was thinking of going in the direction of showing that $G$ is incomplete, so if incomplete $g$ as a derivative of $h$ the lead to lead does not hold, is that the right direction? I would be happy for a direction or a solution because I am desperate for the question.

Comment: What is $G$? What does “incomplete $g$” mean? What does “lead to lead does not hold” mean?

Comment: I have tried to improve the wording in the first part of your question, but I have problems to understand what you mean in the second part.

Comment: What is $C_{1,0}$? Is $g(z-w)$ integrated along the unit circle? Should the integration be done with respect to $w$ instead of $z$? If so, then $h$ is clearly bounded as $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @MartinR incomplete function =  Doesn't ENTIRE function

Comment: @sranthrop center of the circle at z =0 and the ball of radius is 1 .

Comment: I still don't understand how $h$ is defined. Do you mean $$h(z)=\int_{\color{red}{\partial B_1(0)}} g(z-w)\color{red}{dw}?$$

Comment: yes @sranthrop.....

Comment: Do not merely comment "yes".  Edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
|g(z)|=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if } f(z)=0, \\ |f(z)|+1 & \text{if } f(z)\neq0.\end{cases}
$$
In particular, $|g|$ is continuous and hence bounded on the compact disk $\overline{ B_2(0)}$. Now, if $z\in \overline{B_1(0)}$ and $w\in\partial B_1(0)$, then $z-w\in\overline{B_2(0)}$, and so $g(z-w)$ is bounded. But then also $h$ is bounded on $B_1(0)$.